# MS Access "Object or class does not support the set of events" error when opening a 2003 mdb under 2013?

Tags: microsoft-access

I  am trying to open an Access front end to a set of SQL tables. The mdb is in 2003 format and I am opening it in Access 2013. When the main form opens there is an event triggered. I have remarked out all of the code in the event, closed the form and reopened it and I still get the error "Object or class does not support the set of events". If I remove the event I no longer get the error on that event but I do get it when other events are triggered.

The same MDB opened on a second machine does not give that error at all. This makes me think that there is a reference or file missing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the other machine you opened it on the original machine with 2013?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by original machine? The file is used on several machines. Mine is currently the only one that throws errors.

Comment: "The same MDB opened on a second machine does not give that error at all. This makes me think that there is a reference or file missing." Is this machine the machine that original created the file?

Comment: No it is not the original machine. Neither of the machines are the original.  The machine that is throwing the error is the only one with both 2013 and 2003 installed on it. I am very sure that that is the issue. I have run into other problems with VBA one this machine too.

Comment: It is unlikely to be a reference or file missing then, try repairing Office on the machine that throws up the errors